# Understanding this recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm not too sure how this recursion works

```
def c(s):
    '''Docstring omitted.'''
    return sum([c(i) for i in s]) if isinstance(s, list) else 1
```

I don't understand how the following answers are produced

```
>>> c(['one', 2, 3.5])
3
>>> c(["one", [2, "three"], 4, [5, "six"]])
6
```

From my understanding, the function takes all the elements in their respective lists and then adds them. So for the second call, it should be 'one' + (2 + "three") + 4 + (5 + "six"). However, shouldn't this produce an error since you can't sum a string? I'm not sure how the answers were calculated. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In order to understand the recursion you need to understand the recursion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It counts the leaves on a tree (expressed as lists-in-lists).

If `s` is a list (it is looking at a non-leaf node) it calls itself on each element (sub-tree), adds the results, and returns the total.

If `s` is not a list (it is a leaf node) it returns `1` (regardless of whether `s` is `3.5`, or `5`, or `"six"`, `1` is what gets returned).

Answer (score 0):

The base case of the recursion is the "else 1", which is what is returned when s is anything other than a list. sum() is being called on recursive calls to c(), the only non-recursive return value of which is 1. Therefore, it's just summing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the code like this:

```
def count(objects):
    if isinstance(objects, list):
        return sum([count(items) for items in objects])
    else:
        return 1
```